# Is it possible to select text inside an <a> tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css, selection

I have the following elements:

```
<a> <span>text</span> </a>
```

with a specific action trigged *`onclick`* on the link element.
I'm looking for a way to select the text inside the span without triggering the link.
***NB.*** I can't change the code, but, only the CSS.

---

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry I wasn't able to specify my aim.
I need to select text, in order to copy and paste it from a site that I can't directly modify.
I know how to do it via javascript, but unfortunately the only thing I can do is to force IE to set a different CSS style.
I'm trying to find a way to change the elements visualization in order to allow mouse selection and prevent the event click to be called.
For example: increasing the `<span>` height to make it "taller" than the `<a>` overflowing its parent border.
I'm going to try with CSS `position: relative;` and re-sizing.
A better solution could be change the `z-index` of the `<span>` moving it on a higher layer than the `<a>`, but I think it is not possible to change it for parent/child elements on IE.

Comment: I think you have missunderstand CSS. CSS is used to style contents. You have to move to javascript to handle this that can handle user events on the page.

Comment: you can change the javascript , right ?

Comment: you can do using JQuery/Javascript

Comment: Why you are using `<a>` then?

Comment: An anchor element without an HREF attribute will never be an active link.

Comment: can you change the HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use user-select css property.

```
.example{
user-select: text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about "<a href="javascript:void(0)"> <span>text<span\> </a>"

Then you can select the text inside the span without trigger the link.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using CSS at all... You'll need at least javascript change.

Just try the simple jQuery snippet. Call a method myMethod(this) on click:

```
<a href = "javascript : myMethod(this)l" ><span>text</span> </a>
```

and then

```
function myMethod (currObj) {
var temp = $(currObj).find(span).text();
//alert(temp); -- just to test

}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you could do something like this:

```
$('a').children('span').text();
```

Or

```
$('a span').text();
```

Although you would most likely want to bind this with an event, can I ask what are your trying to get the text for?

```
$('a').on('click', function( e ) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).children('span').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[*I remove your span as I thought it was not necessary.]

```
<a id="txtSel" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="aClick()">your_text<a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function aClick()
    {
        var myTxt = document.getElementById("txtSel").innerHTML;
        alert(myTxt);
    }
</script>
```

I hope I understand what you ask....